# Find and extract values in a column that are in a 6' radius of a value of the same column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, distance

Ok guys, I'm new to VBA and first time posting on here. Here's my situation, I have a list of x, y, z coordinates that represent survey points. In the list each set of coordinates has an assigned feature code; there's only two different ones, (200=ground points) & (311=pole base points). I basically need to find the pole base coordinates and then find all the ground points that are in a 6 ft. radius of the pole base and then put that on a new sheet where I can do further calculations, such as determine the difference in the z values between the pole base point and the ground points.  See screen shot below for how the survey data looks once imported to excel.

I wrote one part of the code to find the pole number and coordinates by looking for the pole feature code "311" and paste it on a new sheet, but I can't seem to figure out how to write the code to find the ground points within the 6 ft radius of the pole. I know I can use the distance formula "=sqrt((a2-a1)^2+(b2-b1)^2)" just not sure how to code it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the first part of my code:

```
Sub embed_slope()
'
'
Dim P As Integer
Dim px As Long
Dim py As Long
Dim pz As Long
Dim gx As Long
Dim gy As Long
Dim gz As Long
P = 311
    For Row1 = 2 To 50
        For Row = 2 To 50
            Cells(Row, 3).Select                'search for pole feature code
            If Selection.Value = "" Then Exit For
            If Selection.Value = "311" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Select      'copy pole number
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Data").Select
                Cells(Row1, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste                   'paste pole number on data sheet
                Sheets("Survey Input").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Select     'copy coorinates
                Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy
                Sheets("Data").Select
                Cells(Row1, 2).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("Survey Input").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next Row
    Next Row1
End Sub
```

[image: Survey Data]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52781682/edit) and include the headers of the survey data?

Comment: You would code it just about the same in VBA: `Distance = Sqr((a2 - a1) ^ 2 + (b2 - b1) ^ 2) `  `Sqr` is the vba square root function.  And both the variables and the result should be declared as type `Double`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need to do, but after analyzing your code, I'm guessing that you want someting like this code below. The procedure is looking for pole base points and copying their data to the `Data` sheet, and then searching all ground points which are in 6 ft. distance from every pole base point and also copying their data to the `Data` sheet. I used the function `fnDistance` to calculate the distance between the points.

```
Sub prcEmbedSlope()

    Dim wbWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim intBaseRow, intGroundRow As Integer
    Dim intTargetRow As Integer
    Dim dblXBase, dblYBase As Double
    Dim dblXGround, dblYGround As Double
    Dim dblDistance As Double

    Set wbWorkbook = Application.ThisWorkbook
    intTargetRow = 1

    'First loop (looking for pole base points)
    For intBaseRow = 2 To 15
        If wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 3).Value = 311 Then
            dblXBase = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 4).Value
            dblYBase = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 5).Value
            'Copy pole base points data to the 2nd sheet
            wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 1).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 1).Value
            wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 3).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 3).Value
            wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 4).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 4).Value
            wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 5).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 5).Value
            wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 6).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intBaseRow, 6).Value
            intTargetRow = intTargetRow + 1
            'Second loop (looking for ground points within 6 ft. distance)
            For intGroundRow = 2 To 15
                If wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 3).Value = 200 Then
                    dblXGround = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 4).Value
                    dblYGround = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 5).Value
                    dblDistance = fnDistance(dblXGround, dblYGround, dblXBase, dblYBase)
                    If dblDistance < 6 Then
                        'Copy ground points data to the 2nd sheet
                        wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 1).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 1).Value
                        wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 3).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 3).Value
                        wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 4).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 4).Value
                        wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 5).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 5).Value
                        wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(intTargetRow, 6).Value = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Survey Input").Cells(intGroundRow, 6).Value
                        intTargetRow = intTargetRow + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next intGroundRow
        End If
    Next intBaseRow

End Sub

Function fnDistance(ByVal dblXG As Double, ByVal dblYG As Double, _
                    ByVal dblXB As Double, ByVal dblYB As Double) As Double

fnDistance = Sqr((dblXG - dblXB) ^ 2 + (dblYG - dblYB) ^ 2)

End Function
```